# Django CBV AttributeError object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При сохранении экземпляра в БД постоянно выдается ошибка

> AttributeError 'UserBill' object has no attribute 'get.

Итак, имеется Django 4 и Python 3.9

**Managers**

```
class PaymentManager:
    """
    Менеджер управления финансовыми операциями пользователей
    """
    def __init__(self, request, model):
        self.request = request
        self.model = model

    def create_bill(self):
        new_bill = self.model.objects.create(
            title=self.request.POST['title'],
            slug=slugify(translit(str(self.request.POST['title']), 'ru', reversed=True)),
            owner=self.request.user
        )
        new_bill.save()
        return new_bill
```

**Views**

```
class BillCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserBill
    form_class = BillCreateForm
    template_name = 'payment/new_bill_form.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_bill = PaymentManager(request=self.request, model=self.model)
        return new_bill.create_bill()
```

**Forms**

```
class BillCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Форма создания счета пользователя
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UserBill
        fields = [
            'title',
        ]
```

**Models**

```
class UserBill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField('Идентификатор', max_length=255, db_index=True, unique=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(TayleUser, related_name='own_bills', verbose_name='Счета', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Баланс', default=1000)

    register_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата регистрации', auto_now_add=True)
    last_visit_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата последнего просмотра', auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Активен', default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Счета'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Счет'
        db_table = 'bills'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('payment_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

Беда в том что каждый раз при заполнении и отправке формы я получаю ошибку **AttributeError 'UserBill' object has no attribute 'get'**. Я пробовал писать и без managers.py прямо во вьхе результат тотже, но при этом в БД все сохраняется. Помогите пожалуйста понять что я упустил.

Спасибо за внимание.

---

**Template.html**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
     Новый счет
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Форма регистрации нового счета пользователя:</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-success" name="create" value="Зарегистрировать">
   </form>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: приложите еще код темплейта пожалуйста, на первый взгляд никаких проблем не видно
вероятно проблема тут ` return new_bill.create_bill()`

Comment: можно попробовать добавить что то такое 
```
form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)```

Comment: @maestro Дописал шаблон в вопрос

Comment: пробовали то что выше написал? подозреваю исходя из первоисходгников, что в ответ на запрос он ожидает увидеть `BillCreateForm`

Comment: Вот до сих пор пробую... У ошибки ноги ростут из BillCreateForm. У меня получилось реализовать все через 'def form_valid' но туда ни как не впихнуть бизнес логику...По поводу Вашего комментария выше (про form = self.get_form() if form.is_valid(): return self.form_valid(form)) пока не понял куда это можно впихнуть...